# closing inaccesible resources

Tags: java, oop

How to manage the right way the state of a resource?

in java, sometimes we have resources that must to be opened and closed like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(File);
sc.close();
```

in complex scenarios is not that easy.

i'm facing this problem

```
foo(){
  return new ClosableResourse();
}

bar(ClosableResourse foo){
  return new NotAccesibleFoo(foo);
}
```

and 2 entities using this `NotAccesibleFoo`. How i can properly close my `ClosableResource` class?

bar() function is the only place where i can close that, but is needed in other entities and not accesible from them.

Comment: need more details please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_java/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64994911)

Consider the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature of Java, and this example:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Bar b = new Bar()) {
            b.bar();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, if `Bar` implements [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), then `close()` is called automatically. This may not match your question's code exactly, but you could chain `close()` like so:

```
class CloseableResource implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("TRACER CR close");
    }
}

class Foo implements AutoCloseable {
    CloseableResource resource = new CloseableResource();

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("TRACER Foo close");
        resource.close();
    }
}

class Bar implements AutoCloseable {
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    void bar() {} 

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("TRACER Bar close");
        foo.close();
    }
}
```

In this case, it is important that client code (such as `Example.java` here) use the try-with-resources pattern.

Comment: thanx, i'll investigate and try to replicate this solution.